# Simple Username and Password logon Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication

I wrote a simple login program using a user name and password. I am just learning the basics of Python so I thought this was an easy project to try.

The program runs just fine but I would like to know how an experienced programmer would improve it, purely for learning and understanding more.

```
usernames = ['jo'] ### open from file with open etc..
pwds = ['jo']      ### open from file with open etc..
adpwd = 'jobloggs'

attempts = 3

def username():
    global attempts
    if attempts == 0:
        admin = input('Access locked, Enter admin password: ')
        if admin == adpwd:
            attempts = 3
        elif admin != adpwd:
            username()
    x = input('User: ')
    if x not in usernames and attempts <= 3:
        print('User not recognised')
        attempts -= 1
        username()
    elif x in usernames:
        print('Hello', x)
        pas = input('Password: ')
        if pas in pwds:
            run()
        else:
            print('Incorrect password')
            username()
def run():
    pass


username()
```

Comment: I think you have a security flaw. In your code, if you have multiple users with multiple passwords, everybody can log in as somebody else with their own password.

Comment: Yeah your right. I would need to change it so the username and password were linked to a data base in a certain cell. So I would need to search the database for a location and match it with another database location for it to continue to improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the reading of passwords, I didn't know you were using a database. I thought you had a file in which you store the passwords. You can store them as a json object, in which the keys are the usernames and the values are the passwords.

```
{
  "jo": "jopwd"
}
```

You can then read the password table from disk using:

```
import json
with open('password_table.json', 'r') as f:
    passwords = json.load(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to checking the password for the user that's trying to login, I'd avoid recursion and the globals, and write the code without nesting the conditions too much:

```
USER_CREDS = {'jo': 'jopwd'}      ### open from file with open etc..
ADMIN_PASSWD = 'jobloggs'

def authenticate_and_run():
    attempts_remaining = 3
    while True:
        if attempts_remaining <= 0:
            if input('Access locked, Enter admin password: ') == ADMIN_PASSWD:
                attempts_remaining = 3
            continue
        else:
            attempts_remaining -= 1

        username = input('User: ')
        if username not in USER_CREDS:
            print('User not recognised')
            continue

        print('Hello', username)
        if input('Password: ') != USER_CREDS[username]:
            print('Incorrect password')
            continue

        run()
        break

def run():
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    authenticate_and_run()
```